# how to go back to the current previous view in one controller's button action in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am trying to do if user give correct password it will go back to the current last view controller where i was,like in Ios if u enter background in your app and after sometime you enter foreground then you will go back  to the last view i.e where you was before entering background.please tell me how to implement this.

Comment: my problem is, I am invoking a page from app delegate called password view controller in password view controller i am checking whether given password is correct or not, if correct it will back to the immediate previous page but i can't implement this

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pop to the root controller you can use popToRootViewControllerAnimated.

`[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
From Apple doc of UINavigationController

popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.
`- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`
If you have set up a `UINavigationController` and its root controller is called A, then if you navigate from A to B and then from B to C you have two possibilities to come back to a previous controller (you can have others but I list the main ones):

navigate back from C to B with `popViewControllerAnimated`
navigate back from C to A with `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`

Comment: i am  not using navigation view controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a modal view controller that is not actually added to you parent controllers hierarchy (child view controllers) and can be shown and dismissed at your discretion take a look [here](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/) for a great example.

Comment: that is actually a really old tutorial but the general concept is still the same.

Comment: your example work fine. but i have app delegate controller from where i call my passwordviewcontroller but in passwordviewcontroller's button action i want to call my immediate previous view controller from where app enter in the background.

Comment: does your app always enter the background when you load the passwordviewcontroller, are you doing some sort of web authentication or is this just a situation that can arise by chance? and are you loading a view controller before the passwordviewcontroller? i.e. appDelegate -> otherController -> passwordController.

Comment: appdelegate-passwordviewcontroller-immediatepreviousviewcontroller.